# Need words to resolve the ambiguity of "interface" in OOP. It can mean either a type defined with the keyword "interface" or an object's accessibility

Tags: programming, disambiguities

In some object-oriented programming languages, the keyword *interface* is used for declaring a type that defines how objects that *implement* (another keyword) it may accept messages (calls) from other objects.  These types declared with the keyword *interface* end up being called *interfaces* themselves.

However, some objects do not implement an interface but also accept messages (again, calls) from other objects.  This is defined simply by what the object makes publicly visible.  This is also commonly called the object’s interface, even though there is no separately defined type for it.

Using the same term for two distinct but related concepts makes writing about them difficult.  I have seen *explicit interface* used to mean the first kind.  However, in C♯ this term has a different meaning than what I’m discussing here: there it means package disambiguation.

I need two different terms for these so that I can separately refer to these two distinct concepts in a way that always makes clear which of the two senses I mean, and I need this pair of terms to work for every object-oriented programming language that exists.

#### A little background for clarity

When Java, and later C♯, decided to create a type that did not allow implementation code to exist in it but only defined a set of accessible methods (a protocol) they decided on *interface* as the keyword for this.  This meant people would come to refer to these types as *interfaces*.

However,  the word *interface* already had another meaning. It meant whatever was accessible by virtue of not being hidden by access modifiers like *private*.  It still also means this, but when people use the word *interface* now, it has become hard to know which of the two senses they mean.

Other languages like C++ have no keyword for this and just call such creations header files.  Thus a C++ programmer can freely talk about *header files* and *interfaces* with no ambiguity resulting.

Comment: *formal/informal interface*? Probably too technical for this site.  Objective-C calls a collection of methods that can be implemented by other classes outside inheritance specifically a *protocol*, which only disambiguates if the language strictly defines what it means.

Comment: All OOP languages call that a protocol.  The question is about how to make clear what is defining that protocol.  As for the "too technical" issue, please see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299218/may-i-ask-a-vocabulary-question-on-stack-overflow

Comment: Wrt to messages I would call it the object's 'event model'.  Also: Interfaces are not only about messages, imo.

Comment: @CandiedOrange - ***cs***.stackexchange.com .  I have a CS degree, and I can throw English vocab at you all day, but I suspect you want an answer that involves more topical knowledge than even I bring to the table, because I'm not quite catching your drift.

Comment: @stevesliva I have one as well and it's failing me because computer science as a whole has failed to resolve this.  That's why I'm asking people with large vocabularies.

Comment: @CandiedOrange - looking at the updates, I *was* catching your drift.  If you don't want to go the objc route and call the latter idea a protocol, you need to come up with a term for the former idea, which would be english words for, "the publicly accessible ways in which an object is interacted with?"  There's a reason *interface* got there first...

Comment: @stevesliva exactly, I am leaning towards "accessible interface" vs "implemented interface" at the moment but am still open to ideas.

Comment: Hey, whoa, whoa, whoa!!!  You what to make this stuff ***clear***???  Are you crazy, man???  You'll put thousands of programmers out of work!!!

Comment: @stevesliva any opinion / ideas?

Comment: Would accessibility interface be better?  As in, "An object's accessibility interface is defined by it's own class.  What is accessible may differ based on the location of the accessing code: same class, same inheritance structure, same package," @stevesliva

Comment: @CandiedOrange - *intrinsic*, *inherent*?   I sort of like inherent since we're talking inheritance.

Comment: "Interface" is the place where two entities meet.  As such it's a *very* general term.  Unless qualified somehow (eg, the "red interface" vs the "blue interface") there will always be problems using that term when attempting to describe any halfway-complex program structure.  In fact, it's probably best to avoid the word entirely and pick new words to describe your language-specific constructs.  ("Object" is another word with similar, though less severe, problems.)

Comment: @stevesliva calling the 2nd kind an "inherent interface" could so easily get confused with inheritance itself but I really like the idea of calling it an "intrinsic interface".  How's this sound: "All objects have an intrinsic interface as defined by the accessibility of their methods and properties."  Just need a good way to refer to the 1st kind.

Comment: @stevesliva I just looked up the antonym for intrinsic: extrinsic.  I'm not familiar with the word be it's definition sounds perfect: "being outside a thing; outward or external; operating or coming from without". Thoughts?

Comment: @CandiedOrange if you explain your terms, people will know what you mean by *intrinsic*.  That is, if you lead by saying, "I'm going to call ObjC protocols and Java interfaces "extrinsic interfaces," and I'm going to call an object's native interface "intrinsic," people will understand.  You're right that it's a nice pairing of antonyms, unlike *inherent*, which would have to be countered with *acquired* or something similar.  OTOH, *native* and *nonnative* might work.

Comment: @stevesliva very true.  Thank you so much.  Knowing the right words helps me think better.  As Terry Pratchett said, "Knowing the right words gives the wizard control."

Comment: I think the ambiguity is usually resolved by context. I think the first kind is sometimes called an _interface class_, and the second would be _class's interface_.

Comment: How does this resolve the ambiguity?  A "class's interface" could mean either kind and "interface class" is an oxymoron.  "interface" and "class" are exclusive keywords used when defining new types.  Either kind of type will have an intrinsic interface defined by it's accessibility.  Either kind of type may have extrinsic interface types that it implements. @Barmar

Comment: It's not an oxymoron. An interface is a kind of class; other classes inherit from it to indicate that they implement the interface.

Comment: No, an interface is a kind of type.  A class is also a kind of type.  One you may implement, the other you may extend.  They can be made to work similarly but they are so different that even if their intrinsic interfaces are exactly the same, switching from one kind to another forces you to recompile any clients that use them.  @barmar

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26313/discussion-on-question-by-candiedorange-need-words-to-resolve-the-ambiguity-of).

Answer (score 1):

I use **API** to describe an object's set of public methods, and **interface** to mean a programming contract defined with the keyword *interface*. I only use *API* to talk about object design when there is no chance of confusion with the API provided by a remote application.

API does mean "application programming interface", so the only benefit of the acronym is to signify a class's public methods rather than any interfaces it may implement.

If I must talk about a remote API and describe how my app connects to it, then I'll use *interface* for my code and *API* for the remote code that I have no control over, as in: "this HTTPRequest object provides an interface to make API calls."

Comment: I'ved used this trick in conversation as well.  With mixed results.  The context changing the meaning is one of the reasons I'm looking for good objective words that can only taken one way.